# How to customize WooCommerce templates to avoid override upon update

Tags: templates, woocommerce-offtopic

I've successfully change the HTML for `archive-product.php` and `content-product.php` pages. Once I updated to the latest Wordpress I found that all the changes I made just gone.

I notice this issue is mentioned everywhere I searched for custom theme development. However, I'm not sure how to do this for WooCommerce pages.

First of all, I don't find templates option in admin panel (maybe my theme problem).

Second, how do I tell WooCommerce to use my custom template?

Third, I'm not sure what to place inside my custom design.

This is how I customized `archive-product.php` page.

```
get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns text-left">
            <!--breadcrumb-->
            <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_main_content hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
             * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
             * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_website_data() - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
            ?>
        </div>

        <header class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns text-left woocommerce-products-header collapse">
        <!--title-->
            <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

            <h1 class="woocommerce-products-header__title page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_archive_description hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
            ?>
        </header>

        <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-6 columns collapse">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook.
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
                 * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
            ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="row small-up-2 large-up-4">
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php #woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?><!--removes ul-->

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_shop_loop hook.
                     *
                     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
                     */
                    do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php #woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_no_products_found hook.
             *
             * @hooked wc_no_products_found - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
        ?>

        <?php endif; ?> 
    </div>


<?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
```

Do share with me any reference for this. As I'm unsure which one to follow and not clear on the exact steps.

As per advised,

I created one folder called `woocommerce` inside my theme and placed the template files like below:

```
my_theme/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php
my_theme/woocommerce/templates/content-product.php
```

However its still pointing to the plugin files.

Comment: Copy your woocommerce templates in your theme folder in folder name _woocommerce_. It's a tested method to override woocommerce templates.

Comment: @AmitChauhan, but how do I define the path so that it knows where to refer to

Comment: You don't need to define the path anywhere, templates will be override on there own.

Comment: @AmitChauhan, please refer my edited post and kindly advise, I still see the plugin templates are used.

Comment: @AmitChauhan, sorry, I got it working now..templates folder is not needed it seems, I didn't read your comment corerctly

Comment: Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it like this::

```
my_theme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
my_theme/woocommerce/content-product.php
```

Comment: @Mukiikumar I am glad to know that. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a woocommerce folder on your root folder and copy the template from the woocommerce plugin (in template folder) to the root folder/woocommerce folder. Edit them to avoid changes on update. Also, the file in the root woocommerce folder must be in the same pattern that are in woocommerce plugin/template folder.

Follow the below link for more details on woocommerce template customization. https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/an-introduction-to-theming-woocommerce-for-wordpress--wp-31577

Comment: noted, how to define the path to the new path here? <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

Comment: Duplicate your theme's page.php file and rename it woocommerce.php.
Find the WordPress loop within your woocommerce.php file. 

Replace your loop with the WooCommerce loop:  <?php woocommerce_content(); ?>

So it will take this page and you can customize it accordingly.